# Show external website articles on Block Drupal

Tags: drupal, feed, drupal-blocks

i'm trying to figure out how I can show posts from an external website (on the same server) in a Drupal standard block. Let's say like "recent_blog_posts" but from an external source.

Is there any tutorial into this subject? Can't find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the external website can provide a RSS feed of its recent content (and it most probably does if it's a blog), then you can use Drupal's Aggregator module (which is in Drupal's core but disabled by default) to show the other's site content in a block.

You can read http://drupal.org/node/289 as a starting point.